# Where to get wireless drivers for ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking, drivers, dell

I am working with a Dell Inspiron 1545. I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my computer and after I was done, I observe that there is no wireless functionality available on my system.

I go to the top right where I can see all the network connections but I dont see any wireless network available.

Do I need to install the drivers for wireless separately? How to do that? and Where can I get those?

Or is the problem something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Default Wireless drivers should be available.

Make sure Enable/WiFi or Enable/Wireless is checked.

Update:

On the top right corner, click the WiFi icon.
On the drop down menu, look for Enable WiFi/Wireless and verify that it is checked.

Comment: where do I check that?

Comment: You answer would be more helpful if you could provide step by step instructions on how to accomplish your suggestions.

Comment: @llt I dont get an `Enable WiFi/Wireless` option in the dropdown.